# Logback SiftingAppender TimeBasedRollingPolicy not able to delete old files of other discriminator keys

Tags: logging, logback, spring-logback

I have defined a SiftingAppender with TimeBasedRollingPolicy, the default value for the discriminator key is "api" and other discriminator keys are "scheduler" and "broker". All my log files were able to roll over daily without any issues.

However logback only able to delete old log files with default discriminator key, it not able to delete other discriminator key log files such as scheduler or broker.

Below is my logback configuration:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <!--timeout>120 minutes</timeout-->
    <discriminator>
        <key>type</key>
        <defaultValue>api</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${type}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>logs/${type}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
                <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>           
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <charset>utf-8</charset>
                <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>
```

Appreciate if anyone can pinpoint what wrong with my configuration.